# How to compare contents of two cassandra keyspaces

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I have two keyspaces in my Cassandra cluster, where the second one has been created as a copy (schema and data) of the first one (using sstableloader).

How can I compare (check) if all the data from first one keyspace is also stored in second keyspace in efficient way?

Remarks (doubts):

1. There is a lot of data in these keyspaces, therefore scanning all rows from both keyspaces and comparing them is something that I would like to avoid.
2. Can I compare sstable files (*Data.db) somehow? Keyspaces has exact same structure, so maybe *Data.db files should be the same (or almost the same)?
3. Maybe there is another efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from comparing each key exists in the other which you want to avoid there isn't really another way. The data files wont be the same cause flushing and compaction wont always write out exactly the same partition keys into the same files.

You can use `nodetool cfstats` to compare estimated number of keys but that will only give you an indication

Having said that, querying a table by partition key is a very fast operation, so for a given table where `col1` is the key, a `SELECT col1 from MYTABLE where col1=<key to check>` should run quite fast. If you use one of the drivers you can take advantage of the paging features to limit the result sets into manageable chunks.

As the example says for the [python driver](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html) you could do something like this (note I've not tested this!)

```
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
query1 = "SELECT key FROM keyspace1.table1"
statement1 = SimpleStatement(query1, fetch_size=1000)
for row1 in session.execute(statement1):
    # search second table here
```

It is a bit recursive and you could probably tweak some driver settings to make this more efficient but I just wanted to show how the driver does paging in this manner.

Hope this helps

Comment: But rows are ordered in file based on clustering keys. So, assuming that I have all data flushed and compacted, Data files should be almost the same, right? Maybe there is a way to check only relevant parts of files?

Comment: @pWoz you could try, however its not something i've seen. you need to decode the file using `sstable2json` (earlier versions) or `sstabledump` (later post 3.0 versions). The files will also not have the same name necessarily